# DateTime.Now.DayOfYear not behaving as expected, causing problems as a Random seed

Tags: c#, datetime, random, seed

I'm using the following method to get a random value from a list of IDs.

```
    private int GetRandomDateBasedSectorId(IEnumerable<int> sectorIds)
    {
        var randomSortTable = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (int id in sectorIds)
            randomSortTable[new Random(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear).Next()] = id;

        return randomSortTable.OrderBy(KVP => KVP.Key).Select(KVP => KVP.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

The reason I'm using `DateTime.Now.DayOfYear` as the seed is because I want to pick the same sectorId every time the method executes in a day, and the next day I'll pick a different random one.

This works to a degree, but it's not perfect. For example Yesterday morning and the night before it was consistently picking a single sector ID, then at some point yesterday it started picking a different sector ID, and today it's still using the same sector ID that it used yesterday afternoon.

I thought `DateTime.Now.DayOfYear` would change at midnight GMT (my current time-zone), but it doesn't seem to be.

Can somebody fill me in on if `DateTime.Now.DayOfYear` behaves differently than I expect it to? If so, is there a way for me to modify this so that I can ensure that it'll pick a new Sector ID from the list at midnight every day?

Comment: Are you sure that the time set on  the machine is correct? Maybe it changed at midnight (os time), which is set off a few hours..

Comment: yeah, the date & time are correct on both my machine and the server I've deployed to.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.DayOfYear` Does change at midNight. So problem is not there.

Problem could be in your system's DateTime. Check if its Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the day changes *during* the method call, you're always just going to be returning the last id in `sectorIds`. You'll be replacing the same key every time, because you're creating a new instance of `Random` (with the same seed) on each iteration. I don't think that's what you want...

It seems to me that a much simpler approach would be:

```
private int GetRandomDateBasedSectorId(IEnumerable<int> sectorIds)
{
    List<int> ids = sectorIds.ToList();
    Random rng = new Random(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear);
    return ids[rng.Next(ids.Count)];
}
```

This will pick the same element *by position* each time. Whether it actually returns the same sector ID will depend on whether the `sectorIds` sequence itself is stable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do it like this:

```
int numberOfItems = randomSortTable.Count;
int index = (new Random(DateTime.Now.DayOfYear).Next()) % numberOfItems;
randomSortTable[index] = id;
```

Thanks
Neelesh